# Maya particle "dust" off of object

Tags: 3d, maya

I am trying to create an effect where glowing "dust" made from a particle simulation is flowing off an object (that looks a bit like glass) while it flies through space. I have got a particle simulation but don't know how to get it detailed or react to air behind the object. I was going to upload a picture of what I have but Maya crashed.

[Here](http://vimeo.com/18624205) are examples of what I want flowing off the object.

Also I was wondering how to create shimmering particles in the background